# Snapshot returned from Firebase database event childChanged on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I fetch data from Firebase when a node is changed:

```
handle = ref?.child("orders").child("4").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in          
    if snapshot.key == "price" {
        print("price: \(snapshot.value)")
    }
    if snapshot.key == "orders" {
        print("orders: \(snapshot.value)")
    }                                 
}, withCancel: nil)
```

But is the above function really the way to do it?

I have tried to setup a if statement to check what values is being return then grab that value from `snapshot.value` but I am worried if I change all my values at once I can't tell from what node `snapshot.value` is coming from.

Comment: BTW, if you really expect `ref` to be non-nil you should be using `ref!` instead ;-)

Comment: @PauloMattos Thanks for the tip! But in this case I have som logic that determines if I should open a connection or not. So I only open a connection on certain items :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for tracking *children nodes changes* that's the way  to do it!

Firebase documentation, for the corresponding `childChanges` database event, provides further details:

> Listen for changes to the items in a list. This event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node. The `FIRDataSnapshot` passed to the event listener contains the updated data for the child.

As such, `snapshot.key` identifies the updated child node and `snapshot.value` the corresponding data.